# How do I make an object run along with the the rectangular circle shaped path using iTween?

Tags: c#, javascript, unity

I have to rotate an object, using iTween, or any other animation software. I am creating a betting game, in Unity 5, which I have to manage at run time. I have been using iTween path, but the object only follows the path, and does not rotate along the path or follow the direction of the circular path.

I tried rotating the object using its transform, but when I changed the velocity of the object, the rotation angle would also change. I had to skip it and use iTween, but this object does not follow the path, as I also used `orienttopath` in iTween script. It's not working properly.

How do I make an object run along with the the rectangular circle shaped path using iTween?

Comment: sorry but... what is exactly a rectangular circle shape?? I've see it some times but still don't know it... its a rectangular shape with its tips rounded?

Comment: Yeah exactly....Its a track like rectangle but instead of two small sides it has two semicircle attached as like this --> ( = ).  Means the "equal to" sigh is rectangle's two longer adjacent sides and brackets shows the end semicircles attached with the longer sides.

Comment: If u are not getting then let me know I will give you more explanation or description.

Comment: Oh!! I understand now, then it has 2 curve sides and 2 straight sides right? I thought that maybe it was something like http://www.vectordiary.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/glossy-button-1.gif  but its totally different... for what is used that ' rectangular circle shapes' ? I can't imagine it

Comment: I have to move an object along with that path and I am using iTween for that. Now do u have any idea?

Comment: And I can say its like a capsule shaped track if we see top view of a capsule then the track which I am talking about is similar with the top view of a capsule. And if really wanna help me out then let me know hoe can I add or attach image of my track that makes u more easily understandable.

Comment: oh I see... nice! Sorry no idea about that, if I had  I would already told you :(

Comment: Hey are you trying to make this - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_game ???

Comment: No I told u previously that its a betting game but I have to rotate objects on a rectangular circle shaped track?